# Update Multiple Row Records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, dreamweaver

First of all, I use PHP Dreamweaver to make a program with phpMyAdmin Database. This program gets my records in a 1st row blank when I submit the button, and the remaining records in a rows are still there which is 2nd row and below, but the records in a 1st row is still on the database, why should it happen? any idea for me to solve this program, it also won't update my record. this makes me sick, i need help please!  tnx...

```
<?php require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php'); 
  mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn); 
  $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name"; 
  $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error()); 
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1); 
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1); 

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
      $count = count($_POST['id']); 
      $submit = $_GET['id']; 

      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
          $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'"; 
          $row_Recordset1=mysql_query($sql1); 
       } 

    if($row_Recordset1){ 
            header("location:lulu.php"); 
            exit; 
    }    
 } 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <table width="634" border="1">
    <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>lastname</td>
       <td>email</td>
    </tr>
   <?php do { ?> 
    <tr>
      <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?> 
      <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];   ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>">                       
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">       </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>  
   </table>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
   <p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lacson, it looks like you have at least 4 instances of this exact same question.

Comment: u detect me, i just can't move for this situation

Comment: @LacsonCruz I think I had given you my updated code of using the while { } loop instead of do while { } .. please review it ... it should work

Comment: thank you so much for your help :) now i still trying to do the best can...

Answer (score 0):

Change your `looping` to `while` instead of `do-while`. Check your generated html then and `print_r($_POST)` after the form submit to see the structure of your `post array`. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is now deprecated.

#### Edit:

```
<?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) { ?> 
<tr>
    <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?> 
        <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];   ?>" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>">                             </td>
    <td>
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: how can i change looping to while?

Comment: He calls `mysql_fetch_assoc()` once before the loop, I think that's why he uses `do-while` instead of `while`.

Comment: Yeah right @Barmar, but at the time of posting the question he didnot posted that part so I asked him to use `while`. :D

Comment: i tried to reverse do and while, now the problem,the row 1 data isn't there

Answer (score 0):

first remove this from line 5 :

```
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1); // I think this not valid it should be only in loop
```

and try by while loop as:

```
 <?php while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
{
 ?> 
    <tr>
      <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?> 
      <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];   ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>">                       
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">       </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }  ?>  
   </table>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
   <p>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried this and it will never get my 1st row blank,tnx for that, but there some kind of problem,it will not updating records, do you have idea?please...

Comment: try echo sql query, see , debuging etc...